# Render viewport preview keeps resetting

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view

I have looked around a lot with many different keywords but can't seem to find anyone having the same problem.
I am basically working on an interior kitchen scene and I am trying to preview the render in cycles but the samples keep resetting when I start changing sliders like exposure etc. Even switching between scene and render buttons on the side causes it to reset. This doesn't happen in a new file but it is a bit annoying because it constantly has to reset the preview while I am trying to see if I have the right exposure and it usually doesn't do this but has happened to a few projects.
Scene isn't too big 1.4mil tris. Have tried turning off all objects and looking for settings. Thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome. Sounds like expected behavior for a [path tracer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_tracing) like cycles. When you change any render or camera related setting, cycles re-calculates all the rays in the scene. I recommend try the render region feature or set the samples to a lower value in order to iterate faster.

Answer (score -1):

wait until the viewport render is finished with your desired amount of samples, I've tried 32, you can then change the exposure/gamma/look/view transform
Edit: you can also pause your render and then change the view settings you like